# What does 「ハイきた。」 mean?

Tags: expressions

Also seen as 「ハイきたぁ～！」.

Maybe it's used among young people.

It seems to express the idea that you have achieved your expectations, or something like that.

I hope someone can explain it better.

Yoroshiku.

Answer (score 10):

It's a colloquial form of `はい、来た` as in "yep, (it's) come" or "yep, (it's) arrived".

The way it seemed to be used when I searched blogs (when written as `ハイきた` and other similar variants) was mainly "just in!", "read all about it!", "scoop!" etc. It was often put as the title in blog posts or just before images etc for dramatic effect.

It also looks like it can have a different meaning when written as `ハイきたぁ～！` and similar, taking the meaning "yep, the time has come!", "yes, it's that time again!", "oh no (not again)!" etc in the context of exams et al.

Answer (score 2):

It's like saying "Here it comes!" if it is in context of 
キターーー(゜∀゜)ーーーー!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

「はい、きたぁ~」　is fairly close to "there we go" in English.

「はい、きたぁ~」 can be used for positive and negative events. 「はい、きたぁ~」being used for pleasant events is more frequent.

One nuance is that when you use 「はい、きたぁ~」 for negative event it would probably correspond more to "there we go again", then to "there we go".

Hope it helps.

Comment: In Japan stand-up commedy is played by mostly two people not one, and 「ハイきたぁ～！」means something funny happened as expected. The speaker expected just that answer from the other.

Comment: @noel_lapin +1 Yep, totally agree. My boss used to use this expression when he would try to drive me toward certain conclusion in a conversation, and I would finally say what he wants me to understand (or to ask).