# What does 強いとこｷﾀ---------- mean?

Tags: translation

a friend just sent me this message but I can't understand, especially that last one character, can someone help me plz

強いとこｷﾀ----------

Comment: Duplicate of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3647/what-does-%e3%83%8f%e3%82%a4%e3%81%8d%e3%81%9f-mean ?

Answer (score 5):

キター comes from the early 2000s messageboard 2ch and can be used to express things from simple “arrived!” “here comes” to “finally!”, “at long last!” and similar feelings. 
It is often spelled in half width katakana because that’s how it was employed in various ASCII art pictures on 2ch and [kaomoji](http://kaomoji-pon.net/tag/%e3%82%ad%e3%82%bf%e3%83%bc/).

I don’t know the context of your conversation but possibly your friend is commenting that you used your strong point in a game (?)